dplyr equivalent to duplicated() to show duplicated rows except the first
What is the dplyr equivalent to df[duplicated(df[,subset]),], that is for each set of duplicates based on subset columns, keeps all the rows but the first match?
This will show all duplicated rows, optionally by subset:
df %>% filter(n() > 1, .by = col)

This is the best SQL-esque I could come up with, using a GROUP BY (I believe dplyr should maintain the row order):
# replace with group_by_all for all columns
df %>% group_by(col) %>% filter(row_number() > 1) 


Use df %>% filter(duplicated(.)) or iris %>% filter(row_number()>1, .by = names(.))

@Onyambu I have updated the question to concern mainly a subset of the columns

Just change your .by to include only the subset

@Onyambu can you post as an answer? I can only find the row_number() approach and no dplyr built-in.

Alternatives by @Onyambu:
df %>% filter(duplicated(df[,cols]))
df %>% filter(row_number() > 1, .by = cols)


Probably you can try something like below
set.seed(0)
df <- data.frame(id = 1:30, matrix(sample(1:3, 90, replace = TRUE), ncol = 3))
cols <- c("X2", "X3")
df %>%
  filter(duplicated(select(., all_of(cols))))

where
> df
   id X1 X2 X3
1   1  2  2  2
2   2  1  2  1
3   3  3  1  3
4   4  1  3  3
5   5  2  1  2
6   6  1  3  3
7   7  3  2  3
8   8  3  2  2
9   9  2  2  3
10 10  2  2  3
11 11  3  3  1
12 12  3  2  1
13 13  1  1  1
14 14  1  3  1
15 15  1  2  3
16 16  2  1  2
17 17  2  1  3
18 18  2  3  1
19 19  2  2  1
20 20  3  2  2
21 21  1  3  1
22 22  3  3  1
23 23  1  2  1
24 24  1  2  1
25 25  1  2  3
26 26  1  2  2
27 27  2  1  1
28 28  1  2  1
29 29  1  2  3
30 30  2  2  3

> df %>%
+   filter(duplicated(select(., all_of(cols))))
   id X1 X2 X3
1   6  1  3  3
2   8  3  2  2
3   9  2  2  3
4  10  2  2  3
5  12  3  2  1
6  14  1  3  1
7  15  1  2  3
8  16  2  1  2
9  17  2  1  3
10 18  2  3  1
11 19  2  2  1
12 20  3  2  2
13 21  1  3  1
14 22  3  3  1
15 23  1  2  1
16 24  1  2  1
17 25  1  2  3
18 26  1  2  2
19 27  2  1  1
20 28  1  2  1
21 29  1  2  3
22 30  2  2  3

